# how can I manipulate the value field of MapReduce?

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

When using MapReduce, each resulting document 'result' is structured like this:

```
{ '_id'   : 123, 'value' :{'sum_donations' 999, 'nbr_visitors':50 }
```

I could access _id and value field by using:

```
db.result.find() OR db.result.find({},{_id:1, value:1})
```

Is there a way to select **_*id***  and **sum_donations** without selecting the **nbr_visitors**? Something like this:

```
{'id': 123, 'sum_donation': 999}
```

Or should I just create another MapReduce function that return that for me?
I was thinking about having one MapReduce Collection and manipulate it to answer different questions.
I tried

```
db.result.find({},{_id:1, value.sum_donations:1})  but it didn't work.
```

Comment: What do you: `db.find.result({},{_id:1, value.sum_donations:1})` didn't work? Do you mean as in you are trying to project `sum_donations` to the root document and it didn't work? So that you are basically trying to get a document like: `{_id: {}, sum_donations: 999}` or are you just trying to minus the other subdocument fields out?

Comment: @Sammaye exactly! Like I want to display {'_id': 123, 'sum_donation': 999}
thanks a lot for mentioning the typo _db.find.result_ I fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems to doing this:

- The `value` field of the MR is not currently manipulatable from the MR itself atm, there is a JIRA for it but it's not exactly on the "list": https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-2517
- The query language of Mongo cannot automatically project your fields to the top level document. Subdocument fields stay in the subdocument.

You could (if your using MongoDB 2.2) use the aggregation framework here with the `$project` operator but I believe this to be super over kill and would slow down your system and your program.

So the best way to do this atm is to just extend your programming to grab the field out of that subdocument. This is probably the most performant, direct and easiest method of doing this atm, to simply code around it.